# Unable to install Pydev on Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, pydev

For some reason, I don't see Pydev ( 2.7.1 ) being seen by Eclipse Helios ( 3.6.1 ). I tried the online install option but repositories not found. I tried the zip files option per the documentation copied the files in dropins, plugin/features folders I could find but didn't help.

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: could you provide us some link what online repository/zip you've tried

Comment: I followed the instructions as given at  http://pydev.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Eclipse Helios may have issues with working with PyDev.  I tried to install it on my Helios 3.7.0 but it would never work--neither online nor the dropins.  It would install properly online but then the perspective wouldn't show up.  I found that after I installed Eclipse Juno 4.2.0 it worked just fine using the online install.